# How to convert a rotated NetCDF back to a normal lat/lon grid?

Tags: r, rotation, coordinates, netcdf, cdo-climate

I have a NetCDF file with rotated coordinates. I need to convert it to normal lat/lon coordinates (-180 to 180 for lon and -90 to 90 for lat).

```
library(ncdf4)
nc_open('dat.nf')
```

For the dimensions, it shows:

```
[1] "     5 variables (excluding dimension variables):"
[1] "        double time_bnds[bnds,time]   "
[1] "        double lon[rlon,rlat]   "
[1] "            long_name: longitude"
[1] "            units: degrees_east"
[1] "        double lat[rlon,rlat]   "
[1] "            long_name: latitude"
[1] "            units: degrees_north"
[1] "        char rotated_pole[]   "
[1] "            grid_mapping_name: rotated_latitude_longitude"
[1] "            grid_north_pole_longitude: 83"
[1] "            grid_north_pole_latitude: 42.5"
[1] "        float tasmax[rlon,rlat,time]   "
[1] "            long_name: Daily Maximum Near-Surface Air Temperature"
[1] "            standard_name: air_temperature"
[1] "            units: K"
[1] "            cell_methods: time:maximum within days time:mean over days"
[1] "            coordinates: lon lat"
[1] "            grid_mapping: rotated_pole"
[1] "            _FillValue: 1.00000002004088e+20"

[1] "     4 dimensions:"
[1] "        rlon  Size:310"
[1] "            long_name: longitude in rotated pole grid"
[1] "            units: degrees"
[1] "            axis: X"
[1] "            standard_name: grid_longitude"
[1] "        rlat  Size:260"
[1] "            long_name: latitude in rotated pole grid"
[1] "            units: degrees"
[1] "            axis: Y"
[1] "            standard_name: grid_latitude"
[1] "        bnds  Size:2"
```

Could anyone show me how to convert the rotated coordinates back to normal lat/lon? Thanks.

Comment: -180 to 180 are not "normal" longitudes. They are just a way to represent the world. 0 to 360 is another way.

Comment: Both ways are commonly used. Conversion to either of them would be fine.

Comment: Would the [gis response](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10808/lon-lat-transformation) answer your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use cdo for this purpose https://code.zmaw.de/boards/2/topics/102

Another option is just create a mapping between rotated and geographic coordinates and use the original data without interpolation. I can find the equations if necessary.

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem. You mentioned there are equations out there. I would be interested. I need to convert rotated lat/long that also use the 0-360 long range into regular lat/long with Datum OSGB36 (England). What equations were you referring to?

Answer (score 7):

NCO's ncks can probably do this in two commands using [MSA](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#msa_usr_rdr)

`ncks -O -H --msa -d Lon,0.,180. -d Lon,-180.,-1.0 in.nc out.nc
ncap2 -O -s 'where(Lon < 0) Lon=Lon+360' out.nc out.nc`

Comment: Does this deal with the rotated pole?

Answer (score 5):

I went through the CDO link as suggested by @kakk11, but somehow that could not work for me. Afte much research, I found a way

First, convert the rotated grid to curvilinear grid

```
cdo setgridtype,curvilinear Sin.nc out.nc
```

Next transform to your desired grid e.g. for global 1X1 degree

```
cdo remapbil,global_1 out.nc out2.nc
```

or for a grid like below

gridtype = lonlat

xsize    = 320  # replace by your value

ysize    = 180 # replace by your value

xfirst   = 1  # replace by your value

xinc     = 0.0625 # replace by your value

yfirst   = 43 # replace by your value

yinc     = 0.0625 # replace by your value

save this info as target_grid.txt and then run

```
cdo remapbil,target_grid.txt out.nc out2.nc
```

In my case there was additional issue that my variables did not have the grid information. so CDO assumed it to be regular lat-long grid. So before all the above-mentioned steps, I had to add grid information attribute to all the variables (in my cases all the variables ended with _ave) using nco

```
ncatted -a coordinates,'_ave$',c,c,'lon lat' in.nc
ncatted -a grid_mapping,'_ave$',c,c,'rotated_pole' in.nc
```

Please note that your should have a variable called rotated_pole in your nc file with the lat long information of rotated pole.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the possibility to do that in R (as the User is referring to it in the question). Of course, NCO and CDO are more efficient (way faster). 
Please, look also at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884694/change-coordinates-to-a-series-of-rasters-with-multiple-layers-in-r).

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

nsat<- stack (air_temperature.nc)

##check the extent
extent(nsat)
## this will be in the form 0-360 degrees

#change the coordinates
nsat1<-rotate(nsat)

#check result:
extent(nsat1)
##this should be in the format you are looking for: -180/180
```

Hope this helps.

[edited]