# Only positive latitude and longitude when importing netcdf in R from paleoView probably wrong projection

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, netcdf4

I used the [paleoview](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/ecog.03031) software to download some variables from past climate, including the mean temperature from 15000BP-10000BP (I could upload a file on request but its a GB at least).

The main problem is that when I read the raster, it contains only positive latitude and positive longitude. I know from the article that this has a 2.5*2.5 resolution.

### Using Raster

I loaded both the raster and ncdf4 libraries to read it using raster

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
```

When I read it using the following code

```
r <- raster("mean_temperature-15000BP-10000BP.nc",  varname = "14000BP-13000BP/13300BP")
```

I get the following info

```
r
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  12  bands)
dimensions  : 72, 144, 10368  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 0.5, 144.5, 0.5, 72.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : Mean.Temperature 
z-value     : 1 
zvar        : 14000BP-13000BP/13300BP
```

As you see the extent is only positive, but I know it has the data for the whole world, when I plot the map I get the following image:

```
plot(r)
```

[image]

which clearly shows the patterns expected with the polar circles having extremely low temperatures and the Antarctica being larger that the arctic.

clearly the  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 is wrong here, and I think that if I figure out whats the actual *coord. ref.* I could reproject it and get the raster in the right format

### Using ncdf4

I tried working with the ncdf4 package to try to get more info from the layer, and this is what I did:

```
nc <- nc_open("mean_temperature-15000BP-10000BP.nc")
```

After reading the layer using the `nc_open` function I see the names of the variables to try to understand more of the layers, here I show the first 10

```
names(nc$var)[1:10]

[1] "window"                  "width"                   "decimals"                "months"                  "latitudes"               "longitudes"              "15100BP-15000BP/15100BP" "15100BP-15000BP/15099BP"
[9] "15100BP-15000BP/15098BP" "15100BP-15000BP/15097BP"
```

So if I keep looking and go to the latitude and longitude names I get:

```
ncatt_get(nc, attributes(nc$var)$names[5])
$units
[1] "degrees north"
```

and

```
ncatt_get(nc, attributes(nc$var)$names[6])
$units
[1] "degrees east"
```

Any idea on how to reproject this rasters to get a latitude that goes from -90, 90 and longitude from -180 to 180 that you would expect in a +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 projections

Comment: Can you post the output from `print(nc)` too?

Comment: These links might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/31549880/786542 | https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/284224/1269

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futureheatwaves/vignettes/starting_from_netcdf.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you could set the extent:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("mean_temperature-15000BP-10000BP.nc",  varname = "14000BP-13000BP/13300BP")
extent(r) <- c(-180,180,-90,90)
```

But note that sometimes longitude in climate data goes from 0 to 360 (not here, I think):

```
extent(r) <- c(0,360,-90,90)
r <- rotate(r)
```

To see more about what's in the ncdf, you can do

```
print(r)
```

Of course you only want to do this is you are really sure about the extent, and you may want to contact the data provider to report this issue.