# Cropping Netcdf rasters in R

Tags: r, netcdf, netcdf4

I am still working in the same project where I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935143/only-positive-latitude-and-longitude-when-importing-netcdf-in-r-from-paleoview-p).

And I am getting by allright, but my processing times are too long, for each NetCDF file I am reading it, getting a stack form several of the time-slices, and then cropping each of those time slices within r, using a code like the one bellow:

```
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(ncdf4.helpers)
library(rworldxtra)
data("countriesHigh")
```

The NETCdf files I have are for all of the world, but I am using only South America, for that I use *countiresHigh* from the *rworldxtra* package to subset it:

```
NONA <- countriesHigh[!is.na(countriesHigh@data$GEO3),]
## get shapefile of South America
SA <- NONA[NONA@data$GEO3 == "South America",]
```

Then using the following code I crop every layer that I need.

```
##Open conection to the layer
nc <- nc_open("C:/Users/mean_temperature-15000BP-10000BP.nc")
```

Now I start a loop

```
for(i in 1:10){
  message(paste("reading layer", i))
  # Read the stack for year i
  r <- stack("C:/Users/mean_temperaturemean_temperature-15000BP-10000BP.nc", varname = age[i])  
  #Change the extent to the correct one
  extent(r) <- c(-180,180,-90,90)
  #Crop it to South America
  r <- crop(r, SA)
  gc()
}
```

#### Problem 1: Can I crop the netcdf once before reading stacks to make this process faster?

I have looked [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/futureheatwaves/vignettes/starting_from_netcdf.html), [here](http://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Netcdf/) and [here](http://geog.uoregon.edu/bartlein/courses/geog490/week04-netCDF.html), and found no answer.

#### Problem 2: If I can crop it, how do I define the extent given that the NETCDF file contains only positive latitude and positive longitude

as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935143/only-positive-latitude-and-longitude-when-importing-netcdf-in-r-from-paleoview-p), the defined extent of the map is not the most usual, but I am basing my cropping in the extent of a shapefile that has the more typical `c(-180,180,-90,90)` extent

Comment: Maybe the [stars](https://github.com/r-spatial/stars) package might be helpful here? This [blog](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/11/23/stars1.html) describes how to read NetCDF.

Comment: Thanks @SeGa I will check it out, seems to be a good package